# Как распаковать .zip без изменения даты создания файлов?

Tags: python, zip

```
extract_dir = 'ext_dir'
with zipfile.ZipFile('mod.zip', 'r') as zf:
    zf.extractall(extract_dir)
```

Распаковываю zip файл и получаю файлы с датой создания == дате распаковки
Как распаковать так, чтобы вся информация о файлах оставалась без изменений?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865861/unzip-file-in-python-but-dont-change-file-created-time

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1222748/454489 не хранится в архиве такой информации.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin по вашей же ссылке "There are extensions for zip to store the Unix timestamp"

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin время модификации хранит. это не время распаковки

Comment: Нашел, что функция shutil.copy2() сохраняет метаданные